# Why do my nosetests repeat tests in an A, AB, ABC fashion when using inheritance

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, inheritance, nose

So I was having issues with my nosetests project, so I isolated the issue and tried to figure it out, but I'm left with some bizarre behaviour. See my script below for reference.

```
from unittest import TestCase

class BaseClass(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        print("defining base class stuff")

    def assert_something(self, expected, actual):
        assert expected == actual, "failed test"


class FirstClass(BaseClass):

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        super(FirstClass, cls).setup_class()
        print("defining first class stuff")


    def test_first_class(self):
        self.assert_something(1, 1)


class SecondClass(FirstClass):

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        super(SecondClass, cls).setup_class()
        print("defining second class stuff")


    def test_second_class(self):
        self.assert_something(5, 4)


class ThirdClass(SecondClass):

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        SecondClass.setup_class()
        print("defining third class stuff")


    def test_third_class(self):
        self.assert_something(13, 13)
```

now if I run the script above. I get the following output in the terminal:

```
(sandbox_venv) michael@Puter:~/workspace/sandbox$ nosetests -v
test_first_class (test_.FirstClass) ... ok
test_first_class (test_.SecondClass) ... ok
test_second_class (test_.SecondClass) ... FAIL
test_first_class (test_.TestThirdClass) ... ok
test_second_class (test_.TestThirdClass) ... FAIL
test_third_class (test_.TestThirdClass) ... ok
```

due to the way I'm inheriting. Its apparent that they are also inheriting the test cases and running them again. This is what I mean by 'A, AB, ABC' in the title.

This is not the desired functionality. I was trying to make the project so that I could run my tests in a specific order, but I could also make each test independent from one another. This way if I was to run ThirdClass tests only, then it would run the setup_class() from each subsequent class but not the tests.

Comment: I could name 'ThirdClass' ~ 'TestThirdClass' But I still wouldn't be able to run tests in isolation

Comment: The test cases are member functions so they are inherited. Any other behaviour when using inheritance would be wrong. Maybe you shouldn't use inheritance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ulrich Eckhardt Thank you for your comment. I have since looked into this further and found there isn't a get the desired functionality using inheritance.

Instead, I removed the inheritance and instead just called the setup_class method in the base_class from each of the classes setup methods. like so:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class BaseClass(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        print("defining base class stuff")

    @classmethod
    def assert_something(cls, expected, actual):
        assert expected == actual, "failed test"


class FirstClass():

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        BaseClass.setup_class()
        print("defining first class stuff")


    def test_first_class(self):
        BaseClass.assert_something(1, 1)


class SecondClass():

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        BaseClass.setup_class()
        print("defining second class stuff")


    def test_second_class(self):
        BaseClass.assert_something(5, 4)


class ThirdClass():

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        BaseClass.setup_class()
        print("defining third class stuff")


    def test_third_class(self):
        BaseClass.assert_something(13, 13)
```